# Getting error while using Dataframe and numpy array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using pandas Dataframe and numpy array, Have trouble accessing the data in Dataframe and using it in calculation.

My Code:

```
  import pypyodbc
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 SQLCommand = ("SELECT * FROM [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table3$]")
 df = pd.read_sql_query(SQLCommand, connection)
 real_earnings = np.array([])
 real_price = np.array([])
 CAPE = np.array([])
 print(df)
 total_rows = df[1].count()
 print("total rows:" +  total_rows)
 CPI_latest = df[8,total_rows]

i = 0
for i in total_rows:
    real_earnings[i] = df[[2,i]] * CPI_latest/df[[8,i]]
    real_price[i] = df[[3,i]] * CPI_latest/df[[8,i]]

connection.close()
```

Couple of errors in my code

1. Getting the total number of records in Dataframe

   ```
         total_rows = df[1].count()
   ```

   Error:

   ```
          return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
     File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in 
     pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)
     File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in 
     pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)
     File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in 
      pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
     (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)
       File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in 
    pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item 
     (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)
      KeyError: 1
   ```

Another doubt, How to access the values in two dimensional dataframe. 
             df[[0,1]]   is not working

Sample date

[image: Sample Data file]

Can anyone please help me in solving the errors.
Thanks!

Comment: check out `numpy.empty()`

Comment: Still getting same error message

Comment: did you check out the documentation? that's what i meant...

Comment: @ArvinthKumar How can we help without any sample data? There are many questions on SO referring to the `KeyError` you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `np.array` must act on an object, so calling the function without any parameters causes an error. Valid alternatives are `np.zeros(0)` and `np.empty(0).`

The syntax `df[1].count()` should be replaced by `df.iloc[:,1].count()`.